# How to run a robot framework script from azure databricks notebook?

Tags: python, robotframework, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

Is it possible to run robot framework test suite using azure data bricks notebook?.
I have a set of robot framework test suite, that uses database library, Operating System library etc.

In my local machine, I install python, pip install all necessary libraries and then run my robot code like
"Python -m robot filename.robot"

I want to do the same using azure notebooks, Is it possible?

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks supports 4 Default Language:

Python,

Scala,

SQL,

R

[image]

I was unable to find any documentation, which shows use of robot framework on databricks.

However, you can try running commands on Azure databricks which you tried on local machine.

Databricks is simply just a cloud infrastructure provider to run your spark workload with some add on capability.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, it gave me a direction on how to try. I am working on the solution based on it.